# How to effectively establish point to point channel using ZeroMQ?

Tags: sockets, zeromq, messaging

I have trouble with establishing asynchronous point to point channel using ZeroMQ.

My approach to build point to point channel was that it generates as many `ZMQ_PAIR` sockets as possible up to the number of peers in the network. Because `ZMQ_PAIR` socket ensures an exclusive connection between two peers, it needs the same number of peers. My first attempt is realized as the following diagram that represents paring connections between two peers.

[image]

But the problem of the above approach is the fact that each pairing socket needs a distinct bind address. For example, if four peers are in the network, then each peer should have at least three ( TCP ) address to bind the rest of peers, which is very unrealistic and inefficient.
( I assume that peer has exactly one unique address among others. Ex. **`tcp://*:5555`** )

It seems that there is no way other than using different patterns, which contain some set of message brokers, such as `XREQ/XREP`.
( I intentionally avoid broker based approach, because my application will heavily exchange message between peers, which it will often result in performance bottleneck at the broker processes. )

But I wonder that if there is anybody who uses `ZMQ_PAIR` socket to efficiently build point to point channel? Or is there a way to bypass to have distinct host IP addresses for multiple **`ZMQ_PAIR`** sockets to bind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Q: How to effectively establish ... well,

Given the above narrative, the story of "How to effectively ..." ( where a metric of what and how actually measures the desired effectivity may get some further clarification later ), turns into another question - "**Can we re-factor the ZeroMQ Signalling / Messaging infrastructure, so as to work without using as many IP-addresses:port#-s as would the `tcp://`-transport-class based topology actually need?**"

Upon an explicitly expressed limit of having not more than a just one `IP:PORT#` per host/node ( being thus the architecture's / desing's the very, if not the most expensive resource ) one will have to overcome a lot troubles on such a way forward.

It is fair to note, that any such attempt will come at an extra cost to be paid. There will not be any magic wand to "bypass" such a principal limit expressed above. So get ready to indeed pay the costs.

It reminds me one Project in TELCO, where a [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) was operated in a similar manner with a similar original motivation. Each node had an `ssh/sshd` service setup, where local-port forwarding enabled to expose a just one publicly accessible IP:PORT# access-point and all the rest was implemented "inside" a mesh of all the topological links going through ssh-tunnels not just because the encryption service, but right due to the comfort of having the ability to maintain all the local-port-forwarding towards specific remote-ports as a means of how to setup and operate such exclusive peer-to-peer links between all the service-nodes, yet having just a single public access IP:PORT# per node.

**If no other approach will seem feasible** <sub>( `PUB/SUB` being evicted for either traffic actually flowing to each terminal node in cases of older ZeroMQ/API versions, where Topic-filtering gets processed but on the `SUB`-side, which both security and network Departments will not like to support, or for concentrated workloads and immense resources needs on `PUB`-side, in cases of newer ZeroMQ/API versions, where Topic-filter is being processed on the sender's side. Adressing, dynamic network peer (re-)discovery, maintenance, resources planning, fault resilience, ..., yes, not any easy shortcut seems to be anywhere near to just grab and (re-)use )</sub> **the above mentioned "stone-age" `ssh/sshd`-port-forwarding with ZeroMQ, running against such local-ports only, may save you.**

Anyway - Good Luck on the hunt!